# ExtAudioFileOpenURL not working on mov?

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation, core-audio

I need a reliable way to extract the audio of a Mov file into RAM.
I've tried using AV Foundation and it fails in providing valid samples , seems that the beginning of the audio is faded, and no one as been able to provide me a working solution.

Then I moved to ExtAudioFileOpenURL and the audio file API, that works perfectly if I supply an AIFF or WAV files, while , when opening a MOV file, it rips about 1.5 secs of valid audio and then gives me back garbage for the rest of the samples.

Anyone as a solution to this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have any code to post? Does there seem to be any patterns to the garbage you're getting?

Comment: Apple just answered me this is a bug :/ I've fall back invoking quicktime on a 32 bit process and pass back the data using XPC....bhaa

Comment: Hi Leonardo, we're running into the same issue. Is this bug represented in Apple Bug Reporting somewhere? We'd like to see more details if possible.

Comment: Yes it has been logged but it's not fixed in 10.9 , I've not checked 10.10 pre-release atm. There're two ways to address this issue at the moment, the first one using avfoundation is to create a mutableComposition and insert your media after a 1 sec delay, then rip the audio from the mutable composition. This is a very weak solution in my opinion, the second one, that's the path I toke, is using a 32 bit quicktime process just for the audio ripping, and pass the data encapsulated in an NSData object...it works quite well at the moment...